# Prove the sequence ${|(−1)^n|}n∈N$ has limit = 1.

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Hello I am working on a problem where I have to prove that a sequence ${a_n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$ may not converge but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |a_n|$ may exist. I am using an example where $a_n = (-1)^n$. I know how to prove that ${a_n},  n \in \mathbb{N} $ does not converge but I am having trouble proving that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |(-1)^n| = 1$. I was wondering if anyone had any idea where I should start. I was thinking proof by induction.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a convergent sequence? I would start there

Comment: $\mid (-1)^n \mid$ just equals $1$, so there is really nothing to prove (if $n > N$, regardless of how we choose $N$, $\mid \mid (-1)^n \mid - 1\mid = 0 < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, which is much stronger than what we need. $a_n$ does not converge since it has two different subsequential limits ($a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$)

Comment: Ok thanks! I wasn't really certain how much I could assume about $|(-1)^n|$ but that definitely simplifies the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n=|(-1)^n|=1$, For given $\epsilon>0$, there exist $M\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-1|=0<\epsilon, ~\text{provided} ~n\geq M$.